# When adding values on jquery i get infinte number

Tags: jquery, math

I want to make a simple addition of every span with the class .part-price, but when I do it comes out in infinite numbers.

This is my javascript (jquery) :

```
var total = 0;
  $(".part-price").each(function() {
    total += Number($(this).text());
  });
  $("#cart-total").text(total);
```

And this is my html :

```
<span class="part-price">0.86</span>
<span class="part-price">1.00</span>
<span>Total: </span><span id="cart-total">0</span>
```

At the moment I only have 2 value, one is 0.86, and the other is 1.00, it should come out as:

0.86 + 1.00 = 1.86

But with my code the result is:

0.86 + 1.00 = 1.8599999999999999

Comment: @NickParsons thank you, found the answer there, have to handle in cents to not have decimals and then convert to euros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not handling your floating point numbers properly. You can use `.toPrecision` to help deal with floating point issues.

See working example below:

```js
var total = 0;
$(".part-price").each(function() {
  total += Number($(this).text());;
});

$("#cart-total").text(total.toPrecision(3));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="part-price">0.86</span>
<span class="part-price">1.00</span>
<span>Total: </span><span id="cart-total">0</span>
```

**Do note:** `.toPrecision()` will return a string instead of a number.